# How can I get the value of an input that is inside a span with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<span id="refOrder_2" class="refOrder">
   <input type="text" value="0" 
      size="3" name="item.Order" maxlength="3" 
      id="Order_2" class="wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
</span>
```

What I would like to do is to trigger a refresh function when the value of the input is not equal to the value of $("#dialogOrder").val()  Can someone explain what selector I would use? I assume it would start with:

```
$('#refOrder_2').
```

but how do I get the value of the input ?

Answer (score 4):

As the `input` has an Id, you can get it directly by this:

```
var value = $("#Order_2").val();
```

Or, if you'd prefer to use the selector of the container, you can do this:

```
var value = $("#refOrder_2 input").val();
```

Both of those will give you the same result, the first one being marginally faster.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `input` has an `id`, you can just refer to it as:

```
$("#Order_2").val()
```

In general, you can use

```
$("#refOrder_2 > input").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of options for this, here are just a few.

Target all inputs that are descendants of `#refOrder_2`:

```
$('#refOrder_2 input')
```

Target all inputs that are children of `#refOrder_2`:

```
$('#refOrder_2 > input')
```

Target all inputs of a specific type:

```
$('#refOrder_2 input:text')
```

Target the first input:

```
$('#refOrder_2 input:first')
```

Or, as has been pointed out in several answers already, your `input` has an ID of its own, so you can access it directly using that.

For more information on selecting elements in jQuery, take a look at the [**jQuery Selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page in the Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a direct descendent inside of a given div you could use

```
$('#refOrder_2 > input').val();
```